# Console app that interacts with Illustrator fails

Tags: c#, com, interop, adobe-illustrator

I have created a C#, .Net 4.5 console application that, during its runtime, interacts with Adobe Illustrator.

- Specifically, it gets/or loads an instance of Illustrator
- Opens documents
- Performs some actions
- Saves and closes the document.

This is all done using `Interop.Illustrator`

- Everything works fine when running via Visual Studio.
- Everything works fine if I execute the app from a command line

My issue though is when I run the app from the Task Scheduler in Windows.

I have set the task to run under my account (an admin account) and run when not logged in.

When it runs (either logged in or not) It exits with the error

```
  Retrieving the COM class factory for component with 
         CLSID {B0D0A647-983E-485B-9A69-45F0382F0D9C} failed due to the following error: 

    80080005 Server execution failed 
          (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

The usual searches tell me to adjust the permissions for DCOM  - though there isn't an entry for Illustrator.

I have tried a couple of different accounts, to run the task under, though nothing is working.

**UPDATE**

It works if i un-check the radio "Run whether user is logged on or not" - odd..

Comment: Could the problem be that there is no desktop on which for Illustrator to run?

Comment: I'm logged in. I am manually running the task too.